# Erlang Code Snippet that shows off its benefits?

Tags: erlang

I'm giving a small presentation to a group of C/C++ programmers who have very little experience with functional languages. Part of the presentation mentions Erlang, and I would like to give a specific small code example.

There is a ton of awesome information on StackOverflow  about how/where Erlang is used and its advantages. One of the most common advantages I see is how it can do a lot with just a little terse code, especially compared to C/C++.

I am looking for a good code snippet of Erlang that simply illustrates these types of benefits. Especially something thats easily done in Erlang with few lines, that would be much more complicated in C/C++.

Anyone have any interesting suggestions?

Comment: Check out my new answer on Pythagorean Triples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [example 4](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html) for an excellent example of Erlang's bit syntax.  I'm sure there are a number of c/c++ developers that will appreciate the brevity of the syntax!

Comment: I like this one, though it doesn't really show off the strengths of Erlang as much as it shows off the strengths of Functional Programming.

Answer (score 3):

I would use an example which shows how easy it is to do concurrency.

So basically write map-reduce (but never ever use that word to describe it to a C programmer).

You could start with showing a program that plays [Fizz Buzz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bizz_buzz), and then proceed to make it concurrent.  Should easily fit a whiteboard, or two pages of powerpoint.

Comment: Interesting idea for me as coincidentally Fizz Buzz is a commonly used example with this group!

Answer (score 3):

A Co-worker suggested using Merge-Sort as an example:

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Merge_sort#Erlang

```
mergeSort(L) when length(L) == 1 -> L;
mergeSort(L) when length(L) > 1 ->
    {L1, L2} = lists:split(length(L) div 2, L),
    lists:merge(mergeSort(L1), mergeSort(L2)).
```

Multi-process version:

```
pMergeSort(L) when length(L) == 1 -> L;
pMergeSort(L) when length(L) > 1 ->
    {L1, L2} = lists:split(length(L) div 2, L),
    spawn(mergesort, pMergeSort2, [L1, self()]),
    spawn(mergesort, pMergeSort2, [L2, self()]),
    mergeResults([]).

pMergeSort2(L, Parent) when length(L) == 1 -> Parent ! L;
pMergeSort2(L, Parent) when length(L) > 1 ->
    {L1, L2} = lists:split(length(L) div 2, L),
    spawn(mergesort, pMergeSort2, [L1, self()]),
    spawn(mergesort, pMergeSort2, [L2, self()]),
    Parent ! mergeResults([]).
```

Answer (score 3):

Pythagorean Triples. Get all number combinations below 30 whereby the 3 numbers make a right angled triangle as it is according to Pythagoras.

```
[{X,Y,Z} || X <- lists:seq(1,30),
            Y <- lists:seq(1,30),
            Z <- lists:seq(1,30), ((X * X) + (Y * Y)) == (Z * Z)].
```

Try doing that in C/C++ , or Java and see if you will avoid a `for loop` if not more than one depending on your skill level  :)

Answer (score 2):

the factorial code snippet is the best i have always used to show how short erlang programs can be

```
-module(factorial).
-export([calculate/1]).

calculate(0) -> 1;
calculate(N) -> N * calculate(N -1).
```

As simple as that. That short program illustrates not only how short Erlang programs can be, But also: `Pattern Matching`, `Function Clauses` and **`Last Call Optimization`**. 
 I always had a C++ version of the same, below:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

long factorial(unsigned int a);

void main() {
    unsigned int a;
    long fac;
    .....
    .....
    return factorial(a); 
}

long factorial(unsigned int x) {
        long fac=1;
        if(x == 0) {return 1;}
        else {
                while(x > 0) {
                    fac *= x;
                    x -= 1 ;
                }
        return fac; } 
}
```

Well, this may not be the shortest C++ version, but i know you get the idea.

Comment: You can use recursion in C/C++.  An equivalent function in C/C++ would be: `int factorial(int N)
{
   if (N == 0) return 1;
   else return N * factorial(N-1);
}`

Comment: perfect ! My C++ is the worst. Thanks @MustafaOzturk

Comment: But the Erlang factorial code above isn't last call optimizable. The last call is the multiplication by N, which is waiting on an arbitrary number of stack returns before the first call to calculate/1 can complete. A calculate/2 is needed to iterate with an accumulator for LCO to work.

Comment: Check out my new answer on `Pythagorean Triples`